# How can my students save their assignments to a folder shared with them in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

In another drive system, I (teacher) created and shared assignment folders with my students.  They would open the assignment, create and name their own document, complete assignment, and then save it to the appropriate shared class folder, labeled by date.  I then had each class set of the same assignment in the same folder, making grading remarkably easy.

I now have Chromebooks, all students have Google accounts, managed through our school system.  I can still create assignments in shared folders, students can open, rename and create their own documents, but they CANNOT move the document to a folder that has been created by me and shared with them, as I was able to do on SkyDrive.  When I/they choose "Move To", "Shared with Me" is NOT available as a destination.

Is this a Google Drive change, a Chromebook issue, or some restriction set up by my system?  Or, fourth option, just some way of managing the folders that I have not thought of?

Comment: I think they need to select the folder under "Shared with me" and "add it to my drive". Then they should be able to add/move files as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## Direct answer

Tell your students to add your folder shared with them to "My Drive" in their own accounts and that after move or add the corresponding files to that folder.

## Explanation

Files owned by the user can't be moved to "Shared with me". At the "root level" of "that place" only could be items that are owned by others could be listed.

Users could organize their own files and folders and files and folders shared with them in "My Drive".

## References

[Organize your files in Google Drive - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375091?hl=en)